# Android Remote Database

Tags: android, database

I'm in the process of developing an Android application that will need to connect to a central database. Users should be able to access records and add records to the database through the application. The data itself will be fairly simple with each record being made up of a number of text fields.

The database will be developed specifically for the application and only needs to be accessed through the application. Initial reading seems to indicate that a web service should be written to parse data into xml format, for use by the app.

Seen as the database is being developed from scratch, specifically for this purpose, I would like to make sure I am heading in the right direction. I have very little experience with databases and would really just like a pointer on where to start reading. Any suggestions on the format the database should take would be greatly recieved too.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have the idea down, if it were me, I would recomend using JSON instead of XML for the Webservice, they work in very similar ways, but JSON is a lot smaller and will make the application noticeably (as in it will make a diference for the user) faster. This is specially true if you are sending large amounts of data.

Take a look at this:
[GSon](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/)

Answer (score 0):

If your familiar with other aspects of Java, you could make the implementation entirely server side by means of JSPs. You could access the database via the phone's browser or any other browser. If you implemented a DAO factory on the server, this would enable you to switch databases from say Oracle, to MySQL etc by means of a properties file.